# Continiously text generation with RNN/LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I found many examples of text generation using LSTM
this is the on of them:

```
# Load Larger LSTM network and generate text
import sys
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils
# load ascii text and covert to lowercase
filename = "wonderland.txt"
raw_text = open(filename).read()
raw_text = raw_text.lower()
# create mapping of unique chars to integers, and a reverse mapping
chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
# summarize the loaded data
n_chars = len(raw_text)
n_vocab = len(chars)
print "Total Characters: ", n_chars
print "Total Vocab: ", n_vocab
# prepare the dataset of input to output pairs encoded as integers
seq_length = 100
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length, 1):
    seq_in = raw_text[i:i + seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i + seq_length]
    dataX.append([char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in])
    dataY.append(char_to_int[seq_out])
n_patterns = len(dataX)
print "Total Patterns: ", n_patterns
# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))
# normalize
X = X / float(n_vocab)
# one hot encode the output variable
y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)
# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
# load the network weights
filename = "weights-improvement-47-1.2219-bigger.hdf5"
model.load_weights(filename)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
# pick a random seed
start = numpy.random.randint(0, len(dataX)-1)
pattern = dataX[start]
print "Seed:"
print "\"", ''.join([int_to_char[value] for value in pattern]), "\""
# generate characters
for i in range(1000):
    x = numpy.reshape(pattern, (1, len(pattern), 1))
    x = x / float(n_vocab)
    prediction = model.predict(x, verbose=0)
    index = numpy.argmax(prediction)
    result = int_to_char[index]
    seq_in = [int_to_char[value] for value in pattern]
    sys.stdout.write(result)
    pattern.append(index)
    pattern = pattern[1:len(pattern)]
print "\nDone."
```

After training the network works as it should: after random seeding it generates some text. But it enters in endless loop, so generated text piece is repeated again and again. I understand that it should work this way, because, we feed last part of generated text into the network, so it predicts the sequence based on previous data.

But I want to make the network to generate different text continiously. How to do it? Maybe I need to make random seeds several time or it is better to use a second network trained some differently so that 2 network would give outputs to each other as seeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different [sampling strategy](https://medium.com/machine-learning-at-petiteprogrammer/sampling-strategies-for-recurrent-neural-networks-9aea02a6616f).

Right now you are using greedy search where you always pick the most probable character as the next one.

You could instead use random sampling to choose the new character according to the probablities your network produced. To have some more control over the sampling process usually a [temperature parameter](https://nlp.stanford.edu/blog/maximum-likelihood-decoding-with-rnns-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) is introduced. This lets you control the diversity of the produced text.